# Is it possible to use Safari Technology Preview for handoff from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari, macos

When I open a page in Safari on my iPhone the handoff icon pops up in the dock on my Mac. However clicking on the icon will open Safari. As I am using Safari Technology Preview as my default browser I would like to know if there is some hack that would enable me to use is as a "handoff browser".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed possible, but only if *Safari Technology Preview* is your default browser as set in **System Preferences → General**. If you use a different browser, then the Handoff will always use the original Safari.